# View SQL 2008 sp_cursorexecute Underlying Query and Execution Plan

Tags: sql-server-2008, execution-plan, cursors

I'm performance tuning a Dynamics AX application and see in a SQL trace a long-running, high-I/O query of the form `exec sp_cursorexecute 1073742882 ...` When I try and run that query in a new SQL Management Studio window, I get an error `Could not find prepared statement with handle 1073742882.` I'm not sure, but it seems that a cached plan is connection-specific. I have no `sp_cursorprepare` in my trace; repeating the use case reveales the same prepared handle ID with a new cursor. Since it's a shared environment I'm connecting to, I think I'd have to reset the app server and trace its startup in order to see it.

- Is there any way to use the cursor's prepared handle ID to see the underlying query?
- Is there any way to correlate a row in `dm_exec_cached_plans` to this cursor?
- Is there any way to see the execution plan via `dm_exec_query_plan` or some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not had to track down cursor activity since SQL2000 i.e. pre-DMV days. The old way would still be viable I assume, use profiler and include execution plans in the trace.

I can't remember if the plan will be included in the sp_cursorexecute call or if you need to go back through the trace and find the sp_cursorprepexec or sp_cursorprepare event associated with the handle.